# How to update data validation for a certain range within a specific column with a master list with Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I have two sheets, both have a column that use data validation in Column G/#7, starting from row #8 and all the way down. I have to edit the data validation every once in a while and match the lists for both sheets. This can be annoying since it starts from row 8 down to row 1000+ and needs to be done for both sheets.

How do you make it so that you have a third sheet called "settings" where there will be a master list where in one column there will be a list of rows and for each row it takes the data and automatically updates the data validation list for both sheet one and sheet two?

e.g.

```
1 | Master List (Title)
2 | John Doe
3 | Jane Doe
4 | Steve Smith
5 | Stacy Smith
```

and it makes the data validation for column 7, row 8+ (all the way down) for BOTH **Sheet 1** and **Sheet 2** as such:

`John Doe,Jane Doe,Steve Smith,Stacy Smith`

And if a name is added, it adds it to the data validation list / updates the list. If a name is removed, it removes it from the data validation list.

-- Photo examples provided:

[image]

[image]

We have a column that uses data validation to list out items.

We also have a "master list" with all those items. If I update that "master list" I want the data validation to be updated so I don't have to go into the settings for data validation but only update my list since it is always changing so I can have an updated dropdown for that column.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot image your goal. In order to correctly understand about it, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the input and output situations?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike let me explain better. I have Sheet #1 and Sheet #2. Both these sheets have the same column with the same data validation list. I want to create Sheet #3 where I can make a list of names (row by row) and whenever that list is updated, it changes the data validation for Sheet #1 and Sheet #2 (the columns on Sheet #1 and Sheet #2 are both Column G). How do I update data validation by using a list in the spreadsheet rather than having to edit the data validation?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your goal. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: @Tanaike No worries, let me try one more time, and it doesn't have to be the exact scenario I'm asking for: how do I update "data validation" in Sheet 1, column G, row 8-1000 through a list in another sheet? If the list has 10 different names listed row after row, how can I make it so that list updates the data validation list set in Column G from Sheet 1? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your provided information, I cannot still understand about your goal. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: @Tanaike No problem, I have updated my posting with some images to help. I have two images: one is the column with data validation. The other is the "master list". When I update that master list (if I add a new line or change a name) I want the data validation to update for that entire column. How do I do that? I hope that's easier to understand. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to update the datavalidation rules at the column "D" (the range is "D2:D") on the sheet of "Members", when "Master" sheet is updated.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, I would like to propose to run the script using OnEdit trigger.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please set the sheet names of "Master" and "Members" sheets. From your question, I couldn't understand about the correct sheet names. When you want to run the script, please update the cells of "Master" sheet. By this, the datavalidation rules at the cells "D2:D" on "Members" sheet are updated.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const masterlistSheetName = "Master";  // Please set the sheetname.
  const membersSheetName = "Members";  // Please set the sheetname.

  const ss = e.source;
  const master = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (master.getSheetName() != masterlistSheetName) return;
  const range = master.getRange("A2:A" + master.getLastRow());
  const members = ss.getSheetByName(membersSheetName);
  const dataValidation = members.getRange("D2").getDataValidation().copy().requireValueInRange(range).build();
  const length = members.getRange("D2:D").getDataValidations().filter(String).length;
  members.getRange("D2:D" + (length + 1)).setDataValidation(dataValidation);
}
```

#### Note:

- **This sample script is run by the OnEdit trigger. So when you directly run the function `onEdit` at the script editor, an error occurs because the event object is not used. Please be careful this.**
- This sample script supposes that your values for datavalidation rules are put to the cells "A2:A" in "Master" sheet. When you want to change this, please modify the above script.
- This sample script supposes that your datavalidation rules are put to the cells "D2:D" without the empty rows. When you want to change this, please modify the above script.

#### References:

- [Class DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)
- [getDataValidation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdatavalidation)
- [setDataValidation(rule)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationrule)

Comment: Amazing, thank you! This is what I was looking for, I can build on it for my scenario! Thank you again.

Comment: @usernametaken Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. By your cooperation, I could correctly understand about your question and think of the solution. Thank you, too.